# Update objects in Hibernate session when some change happens to DB externally

Tags: hibernate

Does Hibernate updates object in its session when some changes occur in the DB externally(Other than that hibernate session). If not How can i force hibernate to update them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No and you cannot. It isn't possible to automatically receive updates to your object, based on the updates occurring in the database.

Comment: A session's lifetime should be extremely short: just the duration of a transaction, so a few milliseconds. If you open a new session at each transaction, you'll re-read the state from the database, and you'll see what external apps have changed in the database.

Comment: Then what am i experiencing. In spite of starting new session I am not getting the older value. The value get updated only when i restart the app.

Comment: Do you have the 2nd level cache enabled?

Comment: No. not configured explicitly.